# Using column names and count togetger

Tags: sql, join, select, count, google-bigquery

I am new to SQL.

I am currently trying to write a query where i would like to list down all the details in my tables. I am using joins to get the together and everything is working fine. Where i get stuck is when i try to use count with my other columns. The issue is that the count i am referring to is a text field and as per that table the same id appears multiple times and i want to get the count from my query. My query looks like this

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(col4) 
from table1 c 
left join table2 a on c.id = a.id
```

however this does not work. I would appreciate any leads.

Comment: You need a [`group by`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#group_by_clause) clause, otherwise you will obtain a single count for all rows.

Comment: Count is an aggregation, so you need to specify the group of columns you want to aggregate by.
For your query add "group by col1,col2,col3) to the end of the statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use and study on group by. Your code should be something like below.

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(col4) 
from table1 c 
left join table2 a on c.id = a.id
group by col1, col2, col3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `group by` clause

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(col4) 
from table1 c 
left join table2 a on c.id = a.id
group by col1, col2, col3
```